# How to get count(percentage) for columns after each groupby item?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table. Using `sqlite` DB

| Item | Result |
| --- | --- |
| A | Pass |
| B | Pass |
| A | Fail |
| B | Fail |

I want to realize the above table as below using some query.

| Item | Total | Accept | Reject |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1(50%) | 1(50%) |
| B | 2 | 1(50%) | 1(50%) |

How should I construct this query?

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `PIVOT()` if your DBMS supports. Then use `CONCAT` or `||` operator depending on the DMBS.

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
    item, 
    total, 
    SUM(Pass)||'('|| CAST((SUM(Pass)*1.0/total*1.0)*100.0 AS DECIMAL)||'%)' AS Accept, 
    SUM(Fail)||'('|| CAST((SUM(Fail)*1.0/total*1.0)*100.0 AS DECIMAL)||'%)' AS Reject
FROM 
    (
     SELECT 
         Item, 
         result,
         COUNT(result) OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY result ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS total,
         CASE
           WHEN Result = 'Pass' then 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS Pass,
         CASE
           WHEN Result = 'Fail' then 1
           ELSE 0
         END AS Fail
     FROM t
    ) AS j
GROUP BY item, total
```

**Query explanation:**

1. Since `SQLITE` does not handle `PIVOT`, we are creating the flags Pass and Fail manually using `CASE` statement
2. To calculate `total`, `COUNT` is used as analytical function here. It is basically a shortcut to calculate count and place it in all rows
3. Then in the outer query, we are calculating %s and using `||` as the concatenate operator to concatenate the result with total sum and % of it

See demo in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7e1b70656010384d8b15244b5ca989c2)*

Comment: Thanks @arun , im using sqlite and that doesnt seem to have a PIVOT method

Comment: @BizBaker, Updated the answer. Please try this.

Comment: thanks i do see it working now. I may be pushing it here but would it be possible to explain the logic so that next time i can write it on my own :-)

Comment: Also made one minor change,added a ROUND method so as to restrict the decimal places <\br>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
 SUM(Pass)||'('|| CAST(Round((SUM(Pass)*1.0/total*1.0),2)*100.0 AS DECIMAL)||'%)' AS Accept, <\br>
SUM(Fail)||'('|| CAST(Round((SUM(Fail)*1.0/total*1.0),2)*100.0 AS DECIMAL)||'%)' AS Reject

Comment: @BizBaker, Yeah, `ROUND` would help handling decimal places. Have updated the answer with explanation. HTH!

Comment: sorry didnt get what ur doing here                                                            `COUNT(result) OVER(PARTITION BY item ORDER BY result ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS total,`  especially the `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) `

Comment: @BizBaker, it is basically a shortcut to count all the rows and place it in each row in order to calculate `percentage`. See in the following fiddle that I have explained it is a short form for long query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=84a297a3773c0847cd5567580c3576b9

Comment: So `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` will essentially says SQL to count all rows for each item, and put it in all rows. Does this answer?